# How to return rows that are "missing" from table - Employee Absent Report

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have two tables, like this:

```
master
---------
empcode    INT PRIMARY KEY
name       VARCHAR
dept       VARCHAR 

emp_tx
----------
empcode    INT        references MASTER(empcode)
s_date     DATETIME
```

The `emp_tx` table records the employee "in" and "out" transactions. The column `s_date` stores the time (as a DATETIME value) when the "in" or "out" event occurred. The transactions are recorded from the office region (through Finger Print Biometric System.)

**Example data from emp_tX table:**

```
    empcode   s_datetime
    -------   ------------------    
    1110      2012-12-12 09:31:42  (employee in  time to the office)
    1110      2012-12-12 13:34:17  (employee out time for lunch)
    1110      2012-12-12 14:00:17  (employee in  time after lunch)
    1110      2012-12-12 18:00:12  (employee out time after working hours)
    1112
    etc.
```

**Note:**
If an employee is absent from the office on a given day, then no row will be inserted into the `emp_tx` transaction table for that date. An absence of an employee on a given date will be indicated by a row "missing" for that employee and that date.

Can anyone help me to get a SQL Query that returns the dates that employees were absent, to produce an Employee Absent Report?

The input to the query will be two DATE values, a "from" date and a "to" date, which specifies a range of dates. The query should return all occurrences of "absence" (or, non-occurrences  rather, non, when no row is found in the `EMP_TX` table for an `empcode` on any date between the "from" and "to" dates.

**Expected output:**

If we input '2012-12-12' as the "from" date, and '2012-12-20' as the "to" date, the query should return rows something like this:

```
Empcode  EmpName  Department  AbsentDate  TotalNoofAbsent days
-------  -------  ----------  ----------- --------------------
1110     ABC      Accounts    2012-12-12
1110     ABC      Accounts    2012-12-14                     2   
1112     xyz      Software    2012-12-19
1112     xyz      Software    2012-12-17                     2
```

I've tried this query, and I am sure it is not returning the rows I want:

```
select tx.date from Emp_TX as tx where Date(S_Date) not between '2012-12-23' and '2012-12-30'
```

Thanks.

Comment: let me be the first and doubtfully the last to ask *What have you tried?*

Comment: What is you aim? Can't unsdestand the question

Comment: Did you try anything? If yes, please post your sql query here and experts help you in correcting the query.

Comment: ya sure I will update what i tried the Query

Comment: Do you have employees that work overnight (across a 'day' boundary)?  How should those be counted?  Do you have offices in more than one timezone (especially far apart)?  Is there a 'minimum present' time?  You have both `absentDate` and `totalNoOfAbsentDays` - one is an aggregation, the other appears to be the actual day - which do you want?  Could you at least give desired output data matching your sample data?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thanks,we dont have any branches and No Employees working Overnight,Finally I just want Employee absent dates(if we give input as a date Range(From date and two date)

Comment: A problem of this type is not at all uncommon, and there are some general patterns that we can apply to return result sets of "missing" rows. This problem is not specific to a small geographic area, a specific moment of time, or for an extraordinarily narrow situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an "absence" is defined as the non-appearance of a row in the `emp_tx` table for a particular `empcode` for a particular date (date=midnight to midnight 24 hour period), and ...

If its acceptable to not show an "absence" for a date when there are NO transactions in the `emp_tx` table for that date (i.e. exclude a date when ALL empcode are absent on that date), then ...

You can get the first four columns of the specified result set with a query like this: (untested)

```
SELECT m.empcode     AS `EmpCode` 
     , m.name        AS `EmpName`
     , m.dept        AS `Department`
     , d.dt          AS `AbsentDate`
  FROM ( SELECT DATE(t.s_date) AS dt
           FROM emp_tx t
          WHERE t.s_date >= '2012-12-12' 
            AND t.s_date < DATE_ADD( '2012-12-20' ,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
          GROUP BY DATE(t.s_date)
          ORDER BY DATE(t.s_date)
       ) d
 CROSS
  JOIN master m
  LEFT
  JOIN emp_tx p
    ON p.s_date >= d.dt
   AND p.s_date <  d.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND p.empcode = m.empcode
 WHERE p.empcode IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY m.empcode
     , d.dt
```

---

Getting that fifth column `TotalNoofAbsent` returned in the same resultset is possible, but it's going to make that query really messy.  This detail might be more efficiently handled on the client side, when processing the returned resultset.

---

**How the query works**

The inline view aliased as `d` gets us a set of "date" values that we are checking. Using the `emp_tx` table as a source of these "date" values is a convenient way to do this. Not the `DATE()` function is returning just the "date" portion of the DATETIME argument; we're using a `GROUP BY` to get a distinct list of dates (i.e. no duplicate values). (What we're after, with this inline view query, is a distinct set of DATE values between the two values passed in as arguments. There are other, more involved, ways of generating a list of DATE values.)

As long as every "date" value that you will consider as an "absence" appears somewhere in the table (that is, at least one `empcode` had one transaction on each date that is of interest), and as long a the number of rows in the `emp_tx` table isn't excessive, then the inline view query will work reasonably well.

(NOTE: The query in the inline view can be run separately, to verify that the results are correct and as we expect.)

The next step is to do take the results from the inline view and perform a `CROSS JOIN` operation (to generate a Cartesian product) to match EVERY `empcode` with EVERY `date` returned from the inline view. The result of this operation represents every possible occurrence of "attendance".

The final step in the query is to perform an "anti-join" operation, using a `LEFT JOIN` and a `WHERE  IS NULL` predicate.  The `LEFT JOIN` (outer join) returns every possible attendance occurrence (from the left side), INCLUDING those that don't have a matching row (attendance record) from the `emp_tx` table.

The "trick" is to include a predicate (in the WHERE clause) that discards all of the rows where a matching attendance record was found, so that what we are left with is all combinations of `empcode` and `date` (possible attendance occurrences) where there was NO MATCHING attendance transaction.

(NOTE: I've purposefully left the references to the s_date (DATETIME) column "bare" in the predicates, and used range predicates. This will allow MySQL to make effective use of an appropriate index that includes that column.)

If we were to wrap the column references in the predicates inside a function e.g. `DATE(p.s_date)`, then MySQL won't be able to make effective use of an index on the `s_date` column.

---

As one of the comments (on your question) points out, we're not making any distinction between transactions that mark an employee either as "coming in" or "going out". We are ONLY looking for the existence of a transaction for that empcode in a given 24-hour "midnight to midnight" period.

---

There are other approaches to getting the same result set, but the "anti-join" pattern usually turns out to give the best performance with large sets.

For best performance, you'll likely want covering indexes:

```
... ON master (empcode, name, dept)

... ON emp_tx (s_date, empcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your query is going to get you a ton of results... It will always return all dates for an employee outside the range you gave. You want to check for NOT EXISTS a record BETWEEN your dates.

It may be possible to do this in pure SQL... I can't think of a way offhand without using cursors or something DB-specific. This Java pseudocode will give you 1 employee's absences:

```
List<Date> findAbsences(int empCode, Date inDate, Date outDate) {

    List<Date> result = new LinkedList<Date>();

    Calendar c = new Calendar();
    c.setTime(new Date(2012,12,12));

    while (!c.getTime().after(outDate)) {
        // run query for EMP_TX records between inDate & outDate
        //SELECT 1 FROM EMP_TX WHERE EmpCode = :empid AND S_Date BETWEEN :in AND :out;

        if (!query.hasNext()) {
            result.add(c.getTime);
        }

        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }


}
```