# Count function not returning correct no of records

Tags: mysql, sql

Count function showing none of records incorrectly.

```
DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AbsentReportproctest`$$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AbsentReportproctest`(IN _fromdate DATETIME, IN _todate DATETIME)
    BEGIN 
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE daterange25 (dte DATE);

          CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE daterange26 (dte DATE);

        SET @counter := -1;
        WHILE (@counter < DATEDIFF(DATE(_todate), DATE(_fromdate))) DO 
            INSERT INTO daterange25 VALUES (DATE_ADD(_fromdate, INTERVAL @counter:=@counter + 1 DAY));
             INSERT INTO daterange26 VALUES (DATE_ADD(_fromdate, INTERVAL @counter:=@counter + 1 DAY));

        END WHILE;



    SELECT tp.EMPCODE, d.dte,gc.count
    FROM test_prefixmaster tp
    INNER JOIN(SELECT tp.EMPCODE,COUNT(*)AS count
    FROM test_prefixmaster tp
    JOIN daterange26 d
    LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode)
    AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte
    WHERE tpt.empcode IS NULL
    GROUP BY tp.EMPCODE) gc on tp.EMPCODE = gc.EMPCODE
    JOIN daterange25 d
    LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode)
    AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte
    WHERE tpt.empcode IS NULL;




    DROP TABLE daterange25;

    DROP TABLE daterange26;


    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: please add a lot more details (e.g. sample data, table structure) to explain whats going wrong. this not a code review site

Comment: Please Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162822/how-to-display-string-of-records-row-by-row-in-mysql

Comment: Please check this SQL Fiddle Demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/223a1a

Comment: Check this Similar Information   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099479/select-statement-inside-a-loop-in-a-mysql-stored-procedure

Comment: Check this Similar Question for more Information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023709/how-to-return-rows-that-are-missing-from-table-employee-absent-report

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a typo in your question or not but in your join, i have found out that you didn't supply `ON` clause between your tables,

```
SELECT  tp.EMPCODE,
        d.dte,
        gc.count
FROM    test_prefixmaster tp
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  tp.EMPCODE,
                    COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM    test_prefixmaster tp
                    INNER JOIN daterange26 d
                         -- where is the ON clause here ??
                    LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt
                        ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode)
                            AND DATE (S_DateTime) = d.dte
            WHERE tpt.empcode IS NULL
            GROUP BY tp.EMPCODE
        ) gc
            ON tp.EMPCODE = gc.EMPCODE
        INNER JOIN daterange25 d
                -- where is the ON clause here ??
        LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt
            ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode)
                AND DATE (S_DateTime) = d.dte
WHERE tpt.empcode IS NULL
```

One of the main reasons why it yields incorrect value is *because the joined tables produces cartesian product due to non specifying of the relationship of both tables*. here's an example that an inner join which has not relationship define [Click this link for demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/223a1a/3)

Comment: I want to find the employee absent details for given two dates range?

Comment: can you add sample records with desired result on your question?

Comment: I have given the sample SQL FIddle here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/223a1a

Comment: I want to find the employee absent details for given two dates range

Comment: I want my Output should display like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162822/how-to-display-string-of-records-row-by-row-in-mysql(form the Query in this Question I'm getting the absent details but ,those details I want to get in a Format I'had given there